# Multiple conditions, if/or statement ask

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, countif

I need to write a formula based on multiple conditions, that calculates what percentage of data is completed for each entity. I have created an example dataset below. The condition that will change the calculation is 'Status.' If the status is 'rejected', we will want to take the count of the values entered (4) divided by lets say, 5. If the status is 'invested' or 'due diligence', we will want the count of the values entered (3, 3, and 4 respectively) divided by another specified value. So on and so forth.

| Company | Status | Round | Amount | Fund |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Rejected | Series A |  | VC |
| B | Invested | Seed |  |  |
| C | Due diligence |  | $35M | Debt |
| D | Invested |  | $12M |  |
| F | Initial DD | Series D | $44M | PE |

Can anyone help me find the most efficient way to write this formula? I would appreciate any help here. Thank you so much in advance!